# Retrieve sum from database

Tags: java, sql

```
       try{
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");        
            String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;databaseName=QLLTCK;integratedSecurity=true;";
            Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
            String sql = "SELECT SUM(soSV) AS sumSoSV FROM PHANCONG WHERE tenMH = 'Công nghệ phần mềm chuyên sâu'";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
            if(rs.next()){
                int SumSoSV = rs.getInt("sumSoSV");
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Số sinh viên dự thi: " + SumSoSV);
            }
        }
       catch(Exception sqlex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, sqlex);
        }
```

I cannot retrieve the sum of soSV from my PHANCONG table. Its result is 0. When I tried to use String instead of int, its result is null.
Can someone help me? Thanks.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFVvO.png)

Comment: Are you sure that you have `tenMH = 'Công nghệ phần mềm chuyên sâu'` in your database?

Comment: Yes, I've checked my database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess  you need to add `N` before string literal to handle unicode characters:

```
String sql = "SELECT SUM(soSV) AS sumSoSV FROM PHANCONG WHERE tenMH = N'Công nghệ phần mềm chuyên sâu'"
```